# How can my React App download multiple pdf files at once?

Tags: reactjs, axios, download, fetch, blob

My app is receiving several urls that, pasted in the browser, automatically downloads a pdf file. The way I do a single file download now is using `window.open(url, "_blank")` with the url I choose.

My problem is when I do that in a forof loop to open more than one url, the browser blocks all but one tab.

I tried using Axios and fetch to get a blob but the network tab of the browser says the GET is blocked by CORS. How can this be blocked if I can make the GET pasting in the browser? How can I download multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

CORS is a safety measure in place basically to ensure that you aren't abusing the user by accessing resources from another site as that user (from their machine) that your website should not have access to. It's enforced at the browser level, see [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for more info.

You can get around CORS through a mirroring site/service such as [CORS Anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere); these services make the request for you on the remote machine (meaning you do not have access to the resources as the user) and then send it back to you with proper CORS headers. However, **you cannot get around CORS inside the browser itself**, as this would be a major security vulnerability for the browser to let any site access any resource.

Alternatively, it is pretty simple to make the GET request on the server side and then send the resource back to the client. Either way, there is no way to get resources from other domains without a separate (i.e. not the client) machine doing the requests.

As for why `window.open(url, "_blank")` works, your code from your website in your tab is quarantined from the code in the new window; you cannot access the data in that tab, so the browser has no issue downloading the file, opening the page, or whatever it happens to be (i.e. there is no cross-origin resource sharing occuring).